# Show all entries from a given custom date field

Tags: orderby

I have a channel with a custom field (type "date") called `start`. Now I want a list of all channel entries where the `start` date is today or in the future. So according the EE documentary I'm using the following:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="calendar" dynamic="no" orderby="start" sort="asc" start_on="{current_time format='%Y-%m-%d'}" show_future_entries="yes"}
  {title}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But now I only get a list of all entries with the start date = today. All future entries are not shown. It is also not clear for me what field `start_on` is looking at.

How do I get this working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `start_on` parameter uses the **entry_date**, not the custom date field you defined. To target the custom field, use the `search:` parameter. Also, you need to know how EE stores its date fields: as a Unix timestamp. Which just is a large number.

With EE 2.7+, you can use [Numeric matching](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#numeric-matching), so you could use that too.

```
search:my_custom_date_field=">={current_time}"
```

The `{current_time}` variable without a `format` parameter will output the Unix timestamp for right now, so using that as input for the search:-parameter should give you the desired results.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly the answer I was looking for! Great and many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Low has pointed out the why of your dilemma. There is one other solution you can consider; [Solspace's date field filter](http://www.solspace.com/docs/date_field_filter/), which allows you to remap the default date ordering functionality (which as Low points out is tied to the entry_date).  This way, you can apply the "proper" ordering parameters for the entries loop, making your custom field the date to use.  So then you wind up with something like:

```
{exp:channel:entries
date_field="your_custom_date_field"
date_field_start="2012-12-02 12:01 AM"
date_field_stop="2012-12-04 11:59 PM"
orderby="your_custom_date_field"
sort="asc"
}
    <li><b>{title}</b> - {date_field format="%F %j, %Y at %g:%i %a"}</li>
    {if no_results}
        <li>No results found within this time range.</li>
    {/if}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

And like you attempted to do in your entries loop before, you can then replace your date_field_start param value with the current time variable.

Low would certainly know better than I how this approach would compare efficiency-wise relative to using the search parameter. I've used this add-on, which is now free, and it worked great for me. Just thought I would throw another option out there even though Low's suggestion solved it for you.