# Group entries by month based on custom date picker field

Tags: channel-entries, grouping, date-field-filter

Would anyone know if it is possible to group a list of entries by month, but based on a custom date picker field? To display something like this:

October 2014
Title 1
Title 2
Title 3

November 2014
Title 4
Title 5

December 2014
Title 6

January 2015
Title 7
Title 8 etc etc.

It's for a list of holidays, that I need to display by date order in groups. So the entry_date isn't the actual date if the holiday, I've got a custom field as the holiday start date and another on as the holiday end date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there are a couple ways to approach this.  These links from a previous conversation may help:

[Show all entries from a given custom date field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/show-all-entries-from-a-given-custom-date-field)

http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/date_field_filter/

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually doing someting similar on a site right now to display a list of entries that have been released over the past several months.  It groups by month and displays the corresponding entries underneath.  Here is my base code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="" limit="20" month_limit="2" category_group="4|9|5|3"}
    {date_heading display="monthly"}
        <h4 class="whats-new-month">
            <a name="#{entry_date format="%F-%Y"}">{entry_date format="%F %Y"} Releases</a>
        </h4>
    {/date_heading}
    <div class="whats-new">
        <h6>{title}</h6>
        <ul class="whats-new">
            <li><b>Date Released</b>: {entry_date format="%F %j, %Y"}</li>
            {if cf_master_summary}
                <li><b>Summary</b>: {cf_master_summary}</li>
            {/if}
            <li><b>Where to find it</b>: <a href="">...</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much Todd, that is a real help. Much appreciated.