# ExpressionEngine 3 Date Range

Tags: channel-entries, low-search, date

I am trying to load entries based on a date range that is selected by the user. On the front end of the site I have two input fields, the start day and end day of the date range. In the control panel, I have a custom date field (shipping_date), which is the field that will be compared to the inputted range.

What I would like is to pass those two dates inputted by the user into the channel entries tag in order to limit the entries to only ones where the shipping_date field is between the inputted date range. There are hundreds (if not thousands) of entries so I do not want to load all of them and then do the sorting on the front end.

So I guess my question is two fold:

1. Can ExpressionEngine out of the box limit entries by a date range based on a custom date field? So far my research says this is not possible without an add-on  ([Low Search](https://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#ranges) seems to be able to handle custom field date ranges)
2. How do I pass inputted data from the user into either the channel entries tag or a plugin's tag?

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Are you creating a form on the front-end for the user to submit two date ranges to return channel entries?

Comment: @Miura-shi yes that's exactly what I am trying to do

Comment: Did the Dynamic Parameters feature not suit your needs? Your case may be a little more complex but be sure to check it out:
https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/dynamic_parameters.html

Comment: @Miura-shi I don't think that would work in this case for two reasons- I am using a custom date field rather than the entry date and while there is a start_on variable in the entries tag, I don't believe there is an ''end on" tag. If I'm wrong about that, please let me know!

Comment: I haven't tested this personally but I think you're correct. You should also update your post to let everyone know what version of EE you're on. I currently only work with EE3 and 4.

Comment: It's EE3, I've just updated the title to include that

Comment: The channel entries tag is a bit limiting. It basically takes a pretty linear approach and you're a bit restricted, especially in terms of complex filtering like this. I typically write my on modules/add-ons to create a form and then use the Model service to perform the query. Then you just return your own tag pair for front-end rendering, Does that make sense? I am not sure what your timeline is and the full complexity or your data though.

Comment: Just to recap to, Dynamic Parameters is your option natively out of the box for question #2. In regards to #1, as stated in my previous post I typically write my own module to handle the query/filter aspects. It's more flexible this way to get what you want as you can see, the channel entries tag and dynamic parameters option is still a bit limiting/basic.

Comment: Maybe also look into these, https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on

There is also a  stop_before= parameter, maybe that would help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest attempting to see if the `start_on` and `stop_before` parameters work for with Dynamic Parameters. Run a couple tests to see if this does not suit your needs or work first.

**Dynamic Parameters Documentation**

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/channel/dynamic_parameters.html

**start_on documentation**
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/channel/channel_entries.html#start-on

**stop_before documentation**
https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/channel/channel_entries.html#stop-before

The next steps would be, if this does not suit your needs is to see if there is any module/add-on out their currently to handle more complex filtering like this. A site like https://devot-ee.com/

Out of the box, the EE channel entries tag is fairly linear and basic.

I typically write me own modules and use the Model service to query and filter front-end form submission input and return a custom tag pair. But this depends on your programming capabilities as well.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I just remembered you said you're using a custom_field for the date, so out of the box the Dynamic Parameters will likely not work for you.

Please see if this post is helpful to you at all:

[Show all entries from a given custom date field](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/14477/show-all-entries-from-a-given-custom-date-field)

Comment: Yes, I had tested out dynamic parameters, but it's not suitable in this case. I think I'll end up using an add-on,  thank you for all your help!

Comment: No problem, Brianne! Please check out https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/index.html and https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/services/model/index.html

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this answer now, there is an update to search:numeric_field='' parameter to now include a range in EE4. So you can use this parameter with a custom date field to search by range if you're using EE4.

Here's an article discussing the update: https://expressionengine.com/blog/three-new-content-filters-in-expressionengine-4